# Call Function Clear Button ej2Multiselect Syncfusion Angular onto button event

Tags: angular, multi-select, syncfusion

in mycase i've some multiple multiselect syncfusion and when i click clear button the function clearbutton in multiselect trigered and all the selected value in multiselect cleared, im so confused that i hard find documentation and i think if one of u ever use syncfusion ej2 angular library and know the problem. btw thanks

```
<ejs-multiselect id='multiselectelement' [dataSource]='audience.values' [(ngModel)]="audience.model" #sample [fields]='regs' placeholder='Select a locations'>
              </ejs-multiselect>
```

my expected that i can click that triggered all clear button in mutiselect

i've already search case in syncfusion forum but i dont meet the exactly one

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Syncfusion component.

We have analyzed your requirement and we suspect that your requirement is “**Expecting event when click on the clear button**”. We don’t have specific event while clearing the value using clear button. But while clearing, input value changed as null and trigger change event. So, we would suggest you use the change event when you clear the selected value from the MultiSelect.

**Sample link**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6vatc?file=app.component.ts

**API link**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/multi-select/#change

Could you please check the above details and get back to us with your exact use case scenario, if we misunderstood your query?

Regards,

Vinoth Kumar S

Comment: what I mean is we can call the function using the regular button, for example I have an ordinary button that can clear all the selected items just like showclearall api in multiselect, thanks btw for answering my question